# using MDX Sprite.Draw2D() and the positional problems i have encountered

Tags: c#, position, mdx, sprite

I'm trying to use the Sprite Class in Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D to draw some sprites to my device.

```
GameObject go = gameDevice.Objects[x];
SpriteDraw.Draw2D(go.ObjectTexture,
go.CenterPoint,
go.DegreeToRadian(go.Rotation),
go.Position,
Color.White);
```

GameObject is a class i wrote, in which all the basic information required of a game object is stored (like graphics, current game position, rotation, etc)
My dice with Sprite.Draw2D is the Position parameter (satisfied here with go.Position)
if i pass go.Position, the sprite draws at 0,0 regardless of the Position value of the Object.
i tested hard-coding in "new Point(100, 100)" and all objects drew at 100,100.
I cant figure out why the variable doesnt correctly satisfy the parameter.
I've done some googling, and many people have said MDX's Sprite.Draw2D is buggy and unstable, but i didnt find a solution.
Thus i call upon Stack Overflow to hopefully shed some light on this problem!
Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sprite.Draw2D some time gives problem. Have u tried sprite.Draw its working fine for me.
Here is the sample for Sprite.Draw.

`GameObject go = gameDevice.Objects[x];

SpriteDraw.Draw2D(go.ObjectTexture,
new Vector3(go.CenterPoint.X,go.CenterPoint.Y,O),
new Vector3(go.Position.X,go.Position.Y,O),
Color.White);` and for rotation u can use matrix transform of sprite.

Comment: This was very close to what i did in the end to fix it and i would of been scratching my head for hours more if it wasnt for your answer. thanks :)